# Can node.js replace my javascript timer?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js, timer

I posted here a short while ago today. I had asked whether I could compile JavaScript using jscript.net.

I was told (quite rightly) that jscript.net was old technology and not unsupported) and that I should look at new technology like node.js.

I have taken a look at node.js.  I understand it is a standalone web server that can sit side-by-side with IIS.

I have developed an asp.net application.  It uses a lot of jquery/JavaScript with ajax calls from the client.

I am using a JavaScript timer that calls a url to my generic handler (asmx)to return a image in bytes.

I wanted to see if I could compile JavaScript using jscript.net (hence the original question) which would:

Hide my url address call and perhaps improve performance of my JavaScript.

I have looked at sample code for node.js but could not find anything that would 'replace' my javascript timer.

I admit my javascript/client skills are not that great.

But firstly, is this possible to do with node.js?

I am ready to learn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have taken a look at node.js. I understand it is a standalone web server that can sit side-by-side with IIS.

Node.js is a platform on which you can execute JavaScript (generally on a server). You could certainly use it side-by-side with IIS.

> Hide my url address call and perhaps improve performance of my JavaScript.

You can never hide your request details, there are many many ways to view request details. I would suggest changing your approach if you are security conscious.

> I have looked at sample code for node.js but could not find anything that would 'replace' my javascript timer.

As the Javascript timer is executed client side, you could not use node.js to replace it. You could use node.js to process the timed request that the client sends, like you would do with your .NET handler.

Comment: Excellent. Confirmed what I suspected. You have saved me a lot of time.  Many Thanks